# Column selection error in R with apply loop

Tags: r, apply, googleway

I'm trying to pull data from googlemaps with googleway library.I used Google Elevation API in apply R function

```
Requests <- apply(df, 1, function(x){

                     google_elevation(df_locations =x[c("lat", "lon")],
                     location_type = "individual",
                     key = key,
                     simplify = TRUE)
})
```

but I get the following error

```
df_locations should be a data.frame containing at least two columns of lat and lon coordinates
```

What am i doing wrong with selecting df columns in function?

Thanks

Comment: It's not the selection, but inside an apply, the "x" is a vector. As your input requires a dataframe, you can do df_locations = data.frame(x[c("lat", "lon")]....) ?

Comment: Can't you just use `df` directly in `google_elevation` without the `apply` function?

Comment: I am not familiar with google_elevation.. can you just pass it the whole data frame ? i.e df[,c("lat","lon")] ?

Comment: You don't need the `apply`, you can use the `df` directly. The examples for `?google_elevation` show you how to use a `data.frame` as the input.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved it. No loop was needed. You are right.